# How do you find intersection of two functions

Tags: r

so i have tow log functions,

```
 var1 <- 10 * x * log(x) ^ 2
 var2 <- 100 * x * log(x)
```

I can plot from

```
 library(ggplot2) 
 df <- data.frame(x = rep(x, times = 2), y = c(var1, var2), var = rep(c("10 * x * log(x) ^ 2", "100 * x * log(x)",  each = length(x)))
 ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = var)) + geom_line()
```

Is there a function call in R to help me find the intersection of the var1 and var2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `uniroot()`, if you know the range in which the intersection is going to occur:

```
f1 <- function(x)  10 * x * log(x)^2
f2  <- function(x) 100 * x * log(x)

curve(f1,from=1e-3,to=1e8,log="xy")
curve(f2,add=TRUE,col=2)

uniroot(function(x) f1(x)-f2(x),c(10,1e8))$root
## [1] 22026.47
```

But it's really much easier than that

```
## 10*x*log(x)^2 = 100*x*log(x)
## log(x) = 10
x <- exp(10)    ## 22026.47
```